# xPages radiobutton group onchange event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, xpages

Here is my simple page whit a listbox control that should refresh its values according to the radiobutton group selection. The list box uses a scope variable array as a source. So when I click on the radiobutton I want to change list box values. It works after first/second click then it does not refresh list box then it works again. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.MYARRAY = new Array();
viewScope.MYARRAY.push(["NAME1", "ID1"]);
viewScope.MYARRAY.push(["NAME2", "ID3"]);
viewScope.MYARRAY.push(["NAME3", "ID4"]);
viewScope.MYARRAY.push(["NAME4", "ID5"]);}]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>

<xp:radioGroup id="radioGroupSortBy" defaultValue="0">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="by Name" itemValue="0"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="by Id" itemValue="1"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="listBox1">
        </xp:eventHandler>
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="listBox1">
        </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:radioGroup>

<xp:listBox id="listBox1" style="width:390.0px;height:166.0px">
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var arr = new Array();
            for(var i=0; i<viewScope.MYARRAY.length; i++){
                if(getComponent("radioGroupSortBy").getValue()==0){
                    arr.push(viewScope.MYARRAY[i][0] + " - " + viewScope.MYARRAY[i][1]);
                } else {
                    arr.push(viewScope.MYARRAY[i][1] + " - " + viewScope.MYARRAY[i][0]);
                }
            }
            return arr.sort();}]]>
        </xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xp:listBox>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example does work if you click on radio [image] itself but it is "one click too late" if you click on label.

[This is an onClick partial refresh bug with radio buttons](http://www.assono.de/blog/d6plinks/XPagesOnClickRadioButtonBug).

Add following CCJS code to onClick event:

```
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="listBox1">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            var e = arguments[0] || window.event;
            e = dojo.fixEvent(e);
            if (e.target.type != "radio") {
                e.preventDefault();
                dojo.query("input",e.target).forEach(function(inputNode){
                    dojo.attr(inputNode,"checked",!(dojo.attr(inputNode,"checked")));
                });
            }
            return true;
        ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
```

Answer (score 0):

Radio button events can be strange with certain browsers (IE). Do you have this setting in your xsp properties file?

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21631834

Don't use both onclick and on change.

Howard